# How to access to a java variable in javascript function

Tags: javascript, java

I have a java file called `myJavaFile.java`. Inside this java file, I have the following java code:

```
private void addUploadscript() {

      //my java variable
    String fn = session.getUser();

    html.addElement("<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\">");
    html.addElement("function ajax_post(){");
    html.addElement("var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();");
    html.addElement("var url = \"http://localhost:8080/bunk/inf?cmd=Dialer.opts#\";");
    html.addElement("var vars = \"firstname=\"+fn;");
    html.addElement("\talert(vars)"); 
    html.addElement("hr.open(\"POST\",url,true);");
    html.addElement("hr.setRequestHeader(\"Content-type\",\"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\");");
    html.addElement("hr.onreadystatechange = function() {if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {var return_data = \"my server is reached\";document.getElementById(status).innerHTML = return_data;} } ");
    html.addElement("hr.send(vars);");
    html.addElement("document.getElementById(status).innerHTML = \"processing....\";");
    html.addElement("}");
    html.addElement("</SCRIPT>");

}
```

I already tried to find my response by reading the other topics but I still can not resolve my problem.
I actually tried to do it step by step and display my variables to make sure that I wrote everything fine.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: which variable ? fn ? If yes then just do this: html.addElement("var vars = \"firstname=\"+fn +"\;");

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to output `fn` directly, something like

```
html.addElement("var vars = \"firstname=" + fn + "\";");
```

Javascript allows you to use `'` or `"` for `String`(s), and you could also use [`String.format(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-). Like,

```
html.addElement(String.format("var vars = 'firstname=%s';", fn));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply, I corrected it. I actually am trying my "fn" java variable which is now "firstname" to a php application. This is my final code but I think I have another problem now, I do not know if  "firstname' is sent or not. All I did is just put an alert in both cases (OK or non OK) but nothing is displayed. I also tried to set my "status" input type text on my java side but nothing is displayed. Please let me know if have an idea, I really appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: Huh? Why are you involving Java then? You can make a ReST call to your PHP from Java or from Javascript. Anyway, your *question* appears to be about embedding JavaScript in Java.

Comment: Yes I am embedding javascript in Java. This is an existing application so I have to deal with it because everything is written in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You should change this part of your code:

```
html.addElement("var vars = \"firstname=\"+fn;");
```

For this:

```
html.addElement("var vars = \"firstname=\"" + fn + "\";");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply, I corrected it. I actually am trying my "fn" java variable which is now "firstname" to a php application. This is my final code but I think I have another problem now, I do not know if  "firstname' is sent or not. All I did is just put an alert in both cases (OK or non OK) but nothing is displayed. I also tried to set my "status" input type text on my java side but nothing is displayed. Please let me know if have an idea, I really appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML? If you are opening that page with Google Chrome, do you see any error in the developer console?

Comment: Hello Sanf, I tried to put the generated html but it says that it's too long. I have the generated html. Is there any over way to send it here?

Comment: Post only the generated script tag, just to check if there is any js error.

Comment: ajax_post({document.getElementById('buttonChat').style.display='none';var hr=new XMLHttpRequest();var url='http://localhost:9090/mibew/index.php/operator/login';var fn = document.getElementById('user_name').value; var vars = 'firstname='+fn;hr.open('POST',url,true);hr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');hr.onreadystatechange = function(){var return_data='';if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status ==200{return_data='ok';document.getElementById(status).innerHTML=return_data;}else{return_data='ko';document.getElementById(status).innerHTML =return_data;}}hr.send(vars);}

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related to formatting, but there is a missing ")" in your script, just after checking the readyState and status.

Comment: Well, forget my previous comment. The problem is that the generated script has the fn variable instead its value. Did you try my suggestion in the answer? Look: var vars = 'firstname='+fn;  Instead of "fn" there should be the value.

Comment: I do not understand what you say,I think fn contains my user_name value because my input is <input value=\""+session.getUser()+"\" id=\"user_name\" name=\"user_name\" type=\"hidden\"/>. Am I right? Please let me know

Comment: In the example you posted no, look: `var vars = 'firstname='+fn`. That **fn** refers to the Java variable. Instead of that, you should see the actual value. For instance, if your user is _tatiana_, then it should be: `var vars = 'firstname="tatiana"'`

Comment: Yes I agree with you, var vars should be = 'firstname="tatiana"' . But before var vars = 'firstname="tatiana"'; I tried to alert(fn) and It displays 'tatiana', I am lost.....

Comment: Well, that could be because the **fn** variable is being filled with the value of the user_name field: `var fn = document.getElementById('user_name').value; `. Where do you plan to get the username from then?

Comment: My goal is actually to send this user_name to 'localhost:9090/mibew/index.php/operator/login', so that is why I have hr.send(vars) in my javascript function. "vars" should normaly contains firstname=tatiana. Do you know another simple way to send this "tatiana" to mibew which is a 3rd party app written in php. and I am trying to send "tatiana" from my java application by clicking on a link to this mibew php application. Again thank you, I really appreciate your help SanF

Comment: Yes, I get that you want to post the user name to a PHP service, but my question is: where do you plan to get that user name from? In your code you are trying to get it from an element within your HTML, but you are also trying to send it from Java, so one of them is overriding the other. If you want to use the Java value, just remove this line: `var fn = document.getElementById('user_name').value; `

Comment: Yes, In my java code I have the user name stored in a session variable (session.getUser()) and I want to send it to 'localhost:9090/mibew/index.php/operator/login

Comment: Ok, so remove the line that I mentioned in my previous comment. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: SanF, do you mean I remove this line: var fn = document.getElementById('user_name').value? so how can I send "tatiana" if I remove this line?? Please explain me because I do not understand. Thanks you

Comment: You will send it because the script is being generated by Java (which I assume is what is serving the website) and the _tatiana_ value is being stamped onto Javascript.

Comment: SanF, This is not logic because when I click on my link <div id=\"buttonRight\"><a target='_blank' href='javascript:ajax_post()'>Chat</a></div> I call ajax_post() and if I remove this value how can "my input value can be sent? This is not a form, just an "input" built in java file, do you see what I mean? I try to understand how "tatiana" can be sent if I do not do something with it in my js function ???

Comment: According to your original question, you are setting the _tatiana_ value **inside** the Javascript tag as if it were hardcoded. So, your generated HTML will have the value assigned directly to the variable, without needing to read it from somewhere else.

Comment: You are right, I actually mixed the way I store "tatiana' value, at the begining I put it in a put type text and then I put it into addUploadscript() function. So now I removed the input and maintain  String fn = session.getUser(); inside my addUploadscript() function. It seems like there is no error but the status in put is not set with the returned data to check if "tatiana was sent correctly or not. Is there any other way to send you my function and also my generated html please?

Comment: Try posting the code to an online website like [anotepad.com](http://anotepad.com) or something like that and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Just use single qoute `'` instead of `\"` in all your code that will make it more cleanest, and replace this part :

```
html.addElement("var vars = \"firstname=\"+fn;")
```

By :

```
html.addElement("var vars = 'firstname='+fn;")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply, I corrected it. I actually am trying my "fn" java variable which is now "firstname" to a php application. This is my final code but I think I have another problem now, I do not know if  "firstname' is sent or not. All I did is just put an alert in both cases (OK or non OK) but nothing is displayed. I also tried to set my "status" input type text on my java side but nothing is displayed. Please let me know if have an idea, I really appreciate that. Thank you.